# WPF image manipulation

Tags: c#, wpf, image, brightness

I have some idea of changing brightness in contrast, but i was wondering had a simple solution for changing brightness and contrast

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to merely modify the image as it's displaying on screen, here's a tutorial on using [HLSL (Pixel shaders)](http://khason.net/blog/hlsl-pixel-shader-effects-tutorial/) in WPF and one specifically for [brightness and contrast](http://khason.net/blog/brightness-and-contrast-manipulation-in-wpf-35-sp1/)

If you're looking for how to manipulate the images in memory and save them to disk, I'll need to look harder, but I'm sure I can come up with something. :)

Comment: Both links are broken now